# How to simplify a C-style arithmetical expression containing variables during code generation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, compiler-construction, code-generation

I am trying to optimize expression evaluation in a compiler.

The arithmetical expressions are all C-style, and they may contain variables. I hope to simplify the expressions as much as possible.

For example, `(3+100*A*B+100)*3+100` may be simplified to `409+300*A*B`.

It mainly depends on the distributive law, the associative law and the commutative law.

The main difficulty I encounter is how to combine these arithmetical laws and traditional stack-scan evaluating algorithms.

Can anyone share experiences related to this or similar problems in the context of compiler building?

Comment: Only `+-*/` and parentheses?

Comment: @CaseyChu In fact, all C operators may appears. But I think only considering +-*/() is also acceptable. I am `trying my best` to simplified them.

Comment: You probably need to develop a [rewriting system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting), which would successively apply rewriting rules to the expression. Before doing that, you could have a look at some existing compiler source code, to see how it handles such optimizations. I heard that LLVM source code is very readable.

Comment: The key terms you want to look up are "transitive closure" and "normal form". Note, that there is no such thing as "simple" or "complex", just different forms. You need to decide what forms you want to start with, and what forms you want to translate into to.

Comment: You should also look up 'constant folding'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) combined with strength reduction during the code generation pass of the compilation. Most compiler texts will provide an algorithm to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers usually have some internal normalization rules like "constants to the left". This means `a + 3` would be transformed into `3 + a`, but not vice versa.

In your example,
`(3+100*A*B+100)*3+100` would be normalized into
`(3+100+(100*A*B))*3+100`.
Now it is clear to optimize `3+100`.

Another transformation might be `a*C1+C2` into `(a+(C2/C1))*C1` under the condition that `C1` and `C2` are constants. Intuitively, this normalizes "add before multiply".

Those normalizations are not optimizations. The intention is mostly to group constants together, so constant folding is more effective.