# Sorting mathemtical expression containing variables

Tags: c#

I have developed a mathematical parser using a simple stack algorithm that will handle binary `(+, -, *, /)` operators, unary `(+,-)` operators, parenthesis and variables.

This parser takes and expression like `10+20+(Thickness/(10+20+Height))` and gives the output as `30+(Thickness/(30+Height))` after evaluation (Note: variables won't be evaluated).

But if i gave the expression like `10+(Thickness/(10+Height+20))+20`, parser gives the output as `10+(Thickness/(10+Height+20))+20`.

**I followed below steps for the evaluation:**

1. Tokenized the expression
2. Converted the infix notation to Postfix
   and evaluated.
3. if the expression is `10+20+(Thickness/(10+20+Height))` then postfix will be like `10 20 + Thickness 10 20 + Height + / +` and I'm able to evaluate to value 30 for first two operands,    but, if my expression is like `10+(Thickness/(10+Height+20))+20` then post fix will be `10 Thickness 10 Height + 20 + / + 20 +` since first two operands involve variable `Thickness` I am not able to evaluate it.

So, i would like to reorder the expression `10+(Thickness/(10+Height+20))+20` into `10+20+(Thickness/(10+20+Height))`.

Is there any algorithm to sort the Mathematical expression so that numbers will come first then the variables in an expression or just simply the expression as much as possible.

My main goal is to evaluate an expression which has variable and the values of variables are unknown.

Comment: Hey, do check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18

Comment: Hi Thank you for quick reply, I did check that post, But it requires values for variables before evaluating the expression.I need something similar to the question posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018463/how-to-simplify-a-c-style-arithmetical-expression-containing-variables-during-co